# Use BaseMultiResolutionImage-backed IconImage in HTML img tag

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel

We create a bunch of [BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) objects from class resources that represent variants of the same icon in different sizes, pass that to [BaseMultiResolutionImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/image/BaseMultiResolutionImage.html) and create a multi-sized [ImageIcon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) from it, which may then be used as a drop in replacement for any icon (on Java 9+) and that resizes automatically when placed as an icon on various Swing components (eg.: via `JLabel.setIcon(Icon)`) without much quality loss on HiDPI screens.

Before migrating to such ImageIcons, we simply used `someIcon = new ImageIcon(SomeClass.getResource(String))` to obtain the icons from class resources. This provided us with the ability to reference the associated images in HTML content used to populate for example a JLabel's text (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484488/can-jlabel-have-img-tags)):

```java
new JLabel("<html>Icon in <img src=\"" + someIcon.getDescription() + "\" /> the middle</html>");
```

This worked because the `ImageIcon` constructor took the URL of the resource and set it as the description of the ImageIcon object. It obviously no longer works, since a different constructor is now used, besides each ImageIcon may now have several resource URLs associated with it, with no way of knowing which will be actually used at runtime.

Is there a way to reference multi-sized ImageIcon instances in Swing component HTML `<img>` tag, so that the proper image is auto-selected, as for example, when the same object is set as an icon for a JLabel object?

Here's the pseudo-code that creates an ImageIcon object we'd like to reference in HTML (assumes presence of some PNG files as resources and Java 9+):

```java
package org.stackoverflow;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MultiResIconTest extends JFrame {
    
    public MultiResIconTest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("MultiResIconTest");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel("some label");
        try {
            ImageIcon icon = createMultiResIcon(); // Can we reference this object in an img src attribute...
            label.setIcon(icon); // ...so it works like this?
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        add(label);
                
        setSize(640, 380);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MultiResIconTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private ImageIcon createMultiResIcon() throws IOException {
        BufferedImage base = ImageIO.read(MultiResIconTest.class.getResource("icon.png"));
        BufferedImage first = ImageIO.read(MultiResIconTest.class.getResource("icon@1.25x.png"));
        BufferedImage second = ImageIO.read(MultiResIconTest.class.getResource("icon@1.5x.png"));
        BufferedImage third = ImageIO.read(MultiResIconTest.class.getResource("icon@1.75x.png"));
        BufferedImage fourth = ImageIO.read(MultiResIconTest.class.getResource("icon@2x.png"));
        
        Image[] images = new Image[] {base, first, second, third, fourth};
        Image multiImage = new java.awt.image.BaseMultiResolutionImage(images);
        return new ImageIcon(multiImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but how does one create a _multi-sized `ImageIcon`_ ?

Comment: @Abra, as described in the first paragraph of my question.

Comment: From your question: _at runtime ... the proper image is auto-selected_. What constitutes _the proper image_? Is it according to the size of the `JLabel` displaying the image? Is it according to the size of the `JLabel` parent?

Comment: @Abra, the proper image is returned by `BaseMultiResolutionImage.getResolutionVariant(double, double)`, as described by it's documentation - JComponents call that somewhere in the bowels of Swing, while being painted (Java 9+). I recon that JLabel width and height are provided to it.

Comment: Scratch that. What is most likely being provided to that method is space available for an icon, not the whole JLabel.